# The orientation of the thumbnails of Fujifilm Xt5 HEIF files are wrong in Photo app

Tags: fujifilm, apple, fujifilm-x-t5, apple-photo

This is what the Photo app on iOS looks like after importing the HEIF files from the fujifilm camera.

If I select and open any yellow house photo, the original photo will show up in the correct orientation - landscape - eventually (i.e. after downloaded from iCloud).

My camera is already upgraded to the latest version of firmware (2.10) but it is still happening.

Is it a known issue? How can I fix it, both at the source and for the imported files?

[image]

Comment: What if you browse JPEG files from the same camera?

Comment: Hard to tell... JPEG normally have an orientation indicator . They are usually encoded in the landscape orientation, and the orientation tells the decoder if it should rotate or flip them. But without seeing the actual file (not a "shared" on because these are often re-encoded for sharing) we can't tell if is a problem with the encoded image or the orientation indicator or the browsing app.

Comment: No issue with Jpeg files.